# Read/Write to file - JSON - Body

Tags: python, json, vba

so I am doing a JSON pull in VBA and the body is unusually long. In VBA the maximum string length(possibly the API), so I have written a script where it concatenates the body. When I run my code I am getting an error on my responseText( Run-time error '1002' - Syntax error), I also did a Debug.Print right after the H.responseText and it gave a 500error, which leaves me to assume that there is an error in my body? Would someone please read over my script to see if there is something wrong in the code? If you guys have a better solution of writing this then I would love to know about it! Thank you

```
print("Input filename")
sfilepath = input()
ret = ""

q = 0
with open(sfilepath, 'r') as data:
    stext = data.read()
    print(f"Proceeding with file {sfilepath} that is {len(stext)} characters long")
    while len(stext) >= 128:
        if q == 0:
            ret += 'Body = "'  + stext[:128] + '"\n'
        else:
            ret += 'Body = Body & "' + stext[:128] + '"\n'
        stext = stext[128:]
        q += 1
    if len(stext) > 0:
        ret += 'Body = Body & "' + stext + '"'
    data.close()


with open('output.txt','w') as data:
    data.writelines(ret)
    data.close()
    print("Finished processing and saved to output.txt")
    input()
```

Comment: "In VBA there is a max character length per line" - can you say more about this?

Comment: Hi Tim, sorry I worded it incorrectly. I always seem to get an error in VBA in the body if I don't break it up. I got word from a colleague that its possibly an authentication issue, so I will check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code:

```
print(f"Proceeding with file {sfilepath} that is {len(stext)} characters long")
```

to this:

```
print("Proceeding with file "+ sfilepath +" that is " + str(len(stext))+ " characters long")
```

hope that solves it

[image]